# How to change the breakpoint for slidingNav in Docusaurus

Tags: docusaurus

I have just two header links in [my Docusaurus site](https://nareshbhatia.github.io/mobx-state-router/): Docs & GitHub. I would like to have these links remain in the header until I shrink the browser down to 500px. Unfortunately, the links slide down as soon as the browser shrinks to 1024px. How can I prevent this?

I found the [following code](https://github.com/facebook/Docusaurus/blob/61078e38a928f5b2a79dfeaefaab20a771634673/v1/lib/static/css/main.css#L1416-L1454) responsible for the sliding nav behavior:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .navigationSlider .slidingNav ul {
    background: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

However, if I change the min-width of the media query to 500px, the layout breaks with a big gap below the header bar:

[image]

What's the correct way to change this breakpoin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few changes:
1. Change media query for **.navigationSlider** class to 500px.
2. For the extra gap after header remove padding-top: 100px to 50px from **.navPusher** (For this you need to add another media query)

Comment: Thanks Shashaank - works like a charm! To be safe I overrode a somewhat larger portion of the navigation slider css for my media query. Here it is for everyone's benefit: https://github.com/nareshbhatia/mobx-state-router/blob/master/website/static/css/custom.css#L45-L115. Live site here: https://nareshbhatia.github.io/mobx-state-router/